# WCF Windows authentication with AspNetRoles

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-authentication, asp.net-roles

Is it possible to configure WCF to use Windows credentials to authenticate users and the SQL AspNet Roles provider to store roles and authorizations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the [`ASP.NET Compatibility Mode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx) because as you know WCF could be hosted outside of an ASP.NET context. Obviously by doing this you realize that your service now becomes tied to ASP.NET.

Comment: In what sense would it be tied to ASP.NET?  Can't I self-host the WCF service? or would I need to use IIS?

EDIT: Just read it from the article (This mode requires that the bindings use the HTTP transport and the service itself must be hosted in IIS.)

Comment: I currently have a self-hosted service with a net.tcp binding. I am using the AspSqlMembership and AspSqlRole providers without enabling ASP.NET compatibility mode.  The thing I am interested in is just replacing the membership provider with windows credentials while keeping the sql roles provider intact.